# Generated gaussian kernel saturates the image to white color with opencv in C++

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, gaussian, gaussianblur

I'm trying to implement a function that gives me the Gaussian kernel given a certain standard deviation and dimensions. The output of the function seems correct, but when I apply it using the cv::filter2D function the result I obtain is quite strange. The values saturate to maximum, giving a white color.

The implementation of the function that generates the kernel is the following:

```
    cv::Mat gaussKernel(int kernel_size, float stdDev)
    {
        // For now, only odd kernel_size values
        std::default_random_engine generator;
        std::normal_distribution<float> distribution(0, stdDev);
        float sum_term {0};
        cv::Mat kernel = cv::Mat::zeros(kernel_size, kernel_size, CV_32F);


        // Create kernel
        for (int i = -kernel_size/2; i <= kernel_size/2; i++)
        {
            for (int j = -kernel_size/2; j <= kernel_size/2; j++)
            {
                kernel.at<float>(i + kernel_size/2,j + kernel_size/2) = std::exp(-(pow(i,2) + pow(j,2))/(2*pow(stdDev,2)));
                sum_term += kernel.at<float>(i + kernel_size/2,j + kernel_size/2);
            }
        }

        kernel /= sum_term;

        std::cout << "The kernel is:   " << std::endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < kernel.rows; i++)
        {
            std::cout << "    ";
            for (int j = 0; j < kernel.cols; j++)
            {
                std::cout << kernel.at<float>(i,j) << ", ";
            }
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }

        return kernel;
    }
```

All is being done with greyscale pictures. I expect the error to be related to the codification used in the kernel matrix, but I have tested some stuff and received no result.

--Edit:
Value of stdDev = 1;
Value of kernel_size = 3;

Image:
[Link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3sPSb.jpg)

Part of the code related to reading or modifications of the image:

```
std::string dir {"../resources/ORings/ORing01.jpg"};
cv::Mat original, customKernel;
original = cv::imread(dir);

cv::Mat noisy = original.clone();
cv::Mat clean_1 = original.clone();

customKernel = gauss::gaussKernel(kernel_size, 1);
noisy = gauss::addGaussianNoise(noisy, SNR);
cv::filter2D(clean_1, clean_1, CV_32F, customKernel, cv::Point(-1,-1), 0, cv::BORDER_DEFAULT);
```

Comment: The problem is not reproducible. Please post the values of `kernel_size` and `stdDev`. Please post a sample input image, and the code you are using for reading the image and applying the filter.

Comment: @Rotem I just added the required information.

Answer (score 2):

The cause of the problem is setting the `ddepth` argument of `cv::filter2D` to `CV_32F`.

Setting the argument value to `-1` solves the issue:

```
cv::filter2D(clean_1, clean_1, -1, customKernel, cv::Point(-1,-1), 0, cv::BORDER_DEFAULT);
```

---

Setting `ddepth` argument to `CV_32F` causes the output type of `cv::filter2D` to be `CV_32F` (pixels of type `float`).

The values of the output are in range [0, 255] (same range as the input).
OpenCV convention for pixels of type `CV_32F` (float) is that black is `0` and white is `1`. Values above 1.0 are also white.

There are 3 relevant solutions I can think of:

- Keeping the type of the output `CV_8U` (same as the input), by setting `ddepth` to `-1`.
- Dividing the kernel by 255: `customKernel /= 255.0f;`.
- Dividing the output image by 255: `clean_1 /= 255.0f;`.

Comment: Indeed. And a 4th solution: use a better image display utility that doesn’t saturate images unexpectedly. ;)

Comment: @CrisLuengo You are right, saturating pixels above 1 is the behavior of `cv::imshow`. I keep forgetting it's not MATLAB :)